# Domain accounts available to use only after restart

Tags: macos, catalina, login, domain

We have issue with our OSX Catalina desktop computers and AD domain.
The machines join domain with no problems, but the domain accounts are usable only after login with local account.

Say there's unexpected system crash (restart) or power outage. Afterwards on the login screen the only option for login are local accounts. After that if I logout then I'm able to choose domain account to use.
I've tried all the suggestions I could find after googling, but none of them helped.

Comment: On a Mac with this problem, have you unbound it from the AD domain and then re-binded to the AD server as a troubleshooting step?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that.